# Is there any way to make a border with a spacing between the border and the text?

Tags: html, css, button, padding

I tried a lot of things but none is working and I need help because I wanna make a `hire me` button but I can make a border with a specified separation between text and border.

I have an  image to show what I wanna here:

[image]

HTML Code:

```
<a class="hireme" href="#contact">HIRE ME</a>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a starting point:

```css
.hireme {
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 1ex;
  border: thin solid gray;
  border-radius: 1em;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<a class="hireme" href="#contact">Hire Me</a>
```

In this:

- `text-decoration` takes away the default underline for links
- `padding` puts spacing between the text and the border
- `border` adds the border you want---if that's too dark, try #ccc instead of gray, or there are CSS color pickers on the web
- `border-radius` makes the border rounded
- `text-transform` makes the text render in uppercase
- `color` overrides the color, which usually defaults to blue for links